# getTop for custom view always returning zero

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have built a custom view, where when the user taps on the view it expands. Before it expands I call getTop() to get the current Y coordinate, however it returns zero always. Im calling getTop() from within the custom view class. Is calling getTop() from the class that implements the view not allowed?

```
public void expand(float targetHeight) { //This custom view extends FrameLayout

    int top = getTop(); // returns zero
    rootLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(widthPixels, dpToPx((int) targetHeight)));
    webView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(widthPixels, dpToPx((int) targetHeight)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method getTop() returns the Top position of the view relative to its parent. So maybe is in the position 0 of his parent.

Can you please share your XML so I can have a better understanding of the layout?

Comment: Im adding the view programmatically. So if I get the view's parent can i get the child views y coordinates?

Comment: I guess yes. In this case, I think you should refer to the parent for the real coordinates that you're looking for.